# Pandas fillna function not behaving as expected

Tags: pandas, fillna

I am working on the [Titanic Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) and trying to impute the age column based on the median of age of that title. For example the title Master has a median age of 3.5. For all rows that have title equal to Master and where the age is missing we will impute 3.5. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', index_col=0)

df_1 = df.copy()

df_1.Age[df_1.Name.str.contains('master', case= False)].fillna(df.Age[df.Name.str.contains('master', case=False)].median(), inplace = True)
```

Code above prints the ages for title master including those imputed. However, When printing the df_1 as a whole the missing values appear again. Meaning: the imputation did not affect the df_1 in memory.

Comment: After some more trial and error I hotfixed it this way: 

df_3.Age[df_3.Name.str.contains('master', case= False)] = df_3.Age[df_3.Name.str.contains('master', case= False)].fillna(df_2.Age[df_2.Name.str.contains('master', case=False)].median(), inplace = False)

The following error is returned: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Could this pose issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you're not applying `.fillna()` in the whole dataframe (`df_1`) but instead on the slice of it when you do

```
df_1.Age[<filter condition>].fillna(..., inplace=True)
```

So this created a temporary `Series` object and applied the `.fillna()` method on it and NOT on `df_1`. You could either do `.fillna()` on FULL (NOT the slice) [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to see the effect of `inplace=True` on the original dataframe. Your desired output can be achieved with this though.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', index_col=0)

df_1 = df.copy()

median = df.Age[df.Name.str.contains('master', case=False)].median()

# find the missing age of row containing "master" (case-insensitive) in "Name" 
# and replace with the median age
condition = (df_1.Name.str.contains('master', case=False) & df_1.Age.isna())
df_1.loc[condition, "Age"] = median
```